# Grails form token not available for ajax forms?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

In grails it is easy to add tokens to prevent form double submission and also the click hijacking.

Just add useToken="true" to the form tag:

```
<g:form ... useToken="true" >
```

But, this is not available for formRemote tag. I know that I can do normal form and write js code to transform them into ajax froms with token, but because of that is odd that is not supported by default in the formRemote tag.

Any reason for this, or is just (another) bug in Grails?